# How do i use django rest frameworks to serialise a reverse relationship

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I've got a `Favorites` model which keeps track of each `users`' favorite NFT. I want to display the actual NFT data instead of the NFT id. I'm not quite sure how to do so as only primary keys are being returned.

model

```
class Favorites(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nft = models.ForeignKey(NFT, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

nft model

```
class NFT(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    owner_address = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    token_id = models.IntegerField()
    token_URI = models.URLField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

serializer

```
class FavoritesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Favorites
        fields = "__all__"
```

For example, shown in the django rest framework [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield). Instead of having tracks primary keys, I would like to display the actual track model field values

Comment: Please post the NFT model for more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect that page a little further you will come across this link, and I'll answer quickly with a reference link as you seem competent enough to understand, whilst I contruct a proper answer.

Nested relationships in django rest framework link:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

The documentation describes that to have a relationship rendered by returning certain fields, it is advised that you should create a serialiser for the specific use case, which, in your case

... further answer here which is context specific ... I need NFT model please ...

For example generically:

```
class NFTSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pass
    # add your specific fields
```

And then you can use this serialiser as a field on your `Favourite` serialiser, specifying the keyword argument  `many=True`

```
class FavoritesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nft_favourites = NFTSerialiser(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Favorites
        fields = "__all__"
```

Firstly regarding pagination, please read this section of the documentation, it describes how to create your own custom pagination style, should you choose to do this:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#modifying-the-pagination-style

For completeness, you may need to, or realise that you need to exclude the `NFT_set__id` field which is declared implicitly by `fields = "__all__"` Meta declaration.

Alternatively, I suggest it would be better to declare EXPLICITLY which `fields` you wish to be rendered.

Comment: Nice! Yup I've got an `NFTSerializer` so I just tried `nfts = NFTSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)` and I think it's getting the result I want!

Comment: Can you please post the NFT model so I can complete the answer with context? Thanks.

Comment: Done! Would you happen to know how to paginate the results?

Comment: Absolutely, it's kinda my job to know hehe, ll update my answer just for you :)

Comment: Do you want to paginated `Favourites` or `NFT` ?

Comment: And one final thing, what field or fields do you want to be rendered on the NFT model serialiser?

Comment: Paginated `Favourites` please! So right now in my swagger docs I'm seeing {[NFT, NFT, NFT, ...]}`. I'm trying to display all fields of NFT so I believe that has been covered already in the code

Comment: Great, but now I need you to update me with the viewset you're using :)

Comment: I'm actually just creating stubs right now so the view looks like this `@api_view(["GET", "POST", "DELETE"])
def favorites(request):
    pass`. Was wondering if the serializer would be able to construct a paginated response with attributes such as next, previous, or something similar. But perhaps you're suggesting that can only be done in the view

Comment: Use a ReadOnlyModelViewset and use a default router to register the url in djangos url map :)